# Animate does not end (possible bug?)

Tags: animation

This test code is working and displays always the same histogram and stops at `n=5`.

```
nbars = 20;
data = Array[0 &, nbars];

Animate[
 data = RandomInteger[1, nbars];
 BarChart[data],
 {n, 1, 5, 1}, AnimationRepetitions -> 1
 ]
```

**The following code in which the list `data` should be added to its previous values runs endless, why is it so?**

```
nbars = 20;
data = Array[0 &, nbars];

Animate[
 data = data + RandomInteger[1, nbars];
 BarChart[data],
 {n, 1, 5, 1}, AnimationRepetitions -> 1
 ]
```

Comment: other oddities, notice your `data` gets updated 30+times before n gets to 5, and when it reaches 5 the "play" icon is displayed as if its stopped. Also `AnimationRunning -> False` does not work

Comment: as a workaround do `ListAnimate[Table[data = data + RandomInteger[1, nbars];  BarChart[data], {n, 1, 5, 1}]]`

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you think this is an error?

Comment: i cant see any sense to why it should behave that way or anything inherently wrong with the code.  You should put your version info in the question in case it gets a bug label.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a bug.

`Animate` is a `Dynamic` function, this means that everything within `Animate` is repeatedly updated, regardless of whether the function of steps `{n, 1, 5, 1}` is running or not.
Note that replacing `Animate` with `Manipulate` shows this explicitly.

To understand how this works, try running

```
a = 2;
Animate[Plot[a x + n, {x, 0, 2}], {n, 1, 5, 1}]
```

Then evaluate `a=-2;` in another cell, you will see that the plot output changes.

To update data, and run the code with `Animate[]` instead of `ListAnimate[]`, you can run:

```
nbars = 20;
data = ConstantArray[0, {5, nbars}];
Table[data[[i]] = data[[Max[i - 1, 1]]] + RandomInteger[1, nbars], {i,
    5}];
Animate[BarChart[data[[n]]], {n, 1, 5, 1}, AnimationRepetitions -> 1]
```

Comment: why exactly does it display the "play" button, which would ordinarily indicate that the animation is stopped?  I do agree  dynamic functions are so generally unpredictable its hard to call anything a bug..

Comment: @george2079 The play goes through `n`, `1` through `5`, (which in this case doesn't do anything), it doesn't affect whether or not the function is dynamic. Aside from that every "frame" it's updating `data = data + RandomInteger[1, nbars];`, this is independent of whether play is active.

You can go to "Evaluation" in the menu and uncheck "Dynamic updating enabled", which will stop `data` from being updated.

Comment: Thank you ... now I understand much more.

Answer (score 4):

armed with knowledge that this is a dynamic/manipulate issue we can fix by telling `Manipulate` via `TrackedSymbols` not to track `data` :

```
nbars = 20;
data = Array[0 &, nbars];
Animate[
 data = data + RandomInteger[1, nbars];
 BarChart[data], {n, 1, 5, 1}, TrackedSymbols -> {n}, 
 AnimationRepetitions -> 1]
```

this sort-of works, running through n and stopping, although it updates `data` 6 times, not 5.  (If you set `nbars` large, say 100, you will consistently get a few bars with value 6. ) Additionally, if you manually move the slider after it stops it will update `data` with each move. ( not clear what you actually expect )

If you do this,

```
nbars = 20;
data = Array[0 &, nbars];
ListAnimate[
 Table[data = data + RandomInteger[1, nbars]; 
  BarChart[data], {n, 1, 5, 1}], AnimationRepetitions -> 1]
```

you get exactly 5 frames, that do not change after the first run though.

Comment: This is excellent ...

Answer (score 3):

Answer from Wolfram Technology Group:

In your second example, the value of data is being changed (`data = data + RandomInteger[1, nbars]`) while the expression is getting evaluated, and, as you mentioned, for each change the Animation is repeated. This is As Designed. 
If you look at the `FullForm` of your expression (you can add `//FullForm` at the end of your expression and evaluate it), you can see that `Animate` is basically a `Manipulate` module (with Animator for ControlType and SynchronousUpdating set to True):

```
nbars = 20;
data = Array[0 &, nbars];

Manipulate[
 CompoundExpression[Set[data, Plus[data, RandomInteger[1, nbars]]], 
  BarChart[data]],
 List[
  n, 1, 5, 1, Rule[AnimationRepetitions, 1], 
  Rule[AppearanceElements, 
   List["ProgressSlider", "PlayPauseButton", "FasterSlowerButtons", 
    "DirectionButton"]]
  ],
 Rule[ControlType, Animator], Rule[AppearanceElements, None], 
 Rule[DefaultBaseStyle, "Animate"], 
 Rule[DefaultLabelStyle, "AnimateLabel"], 
 Rule[SynchronousUpdating, True], Rule[ShrinkingDelay, 10.`]
 ]
```

And if you look at the output cell for the first expression (without `FullForm`) by selecting the cell and pressing `Shift+Ctrl+E` (or clicking on "Show Expression" in the "Cell" menu in Mathematica), you can see that the output cell is a `DynamicModuleBox`. It will dynamically update with the updated value of "`data`".